# Javafx : SplitPane resize children

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, splitpane

I fave an .fxml file, in which I have added some `TitledPane` but I cannot resize them in the application. Here is the code:

```
<ScrollPane AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0">
    <SplitPane orientation="VERTICAL" fx:id="splitPane">
        <TitledPane>
            <TextArea fx:id="taTop" wrapText="true" editable="false" prefHeight="100"/>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane>
            <TableView fx:id="tableFrist" minHeight="120" maxHeight="120">
                <columns>
                    <TableColumn fx:id="column" prefWidth="200"/>
                </columns>
            </TableView>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane>
            <TreeTableView fx:id="tableSecond">
                <columns>
                    <TreeTableColumn fx:id="columnTreeS" prefWidth="200"/>
                </columns>
            </TreeTableView>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane>
            <TreeTableView fx:id="tableThird">
                <columns>
                    <TreeTableColumn fx:id="columnTreeT" prefWidth="200"/>
                </columns>
            </TreeTableView>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane>
            <TextArea fx:id="taBot" wrapText="true" editable="false"/>
        </TitledPane>
    </SplitPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

What did I miss, or why I cannot resise the panes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **fitToHeight** and **fitToWidth** attributes to true for ScrollPane:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#fitToHeightProperty

> If true and if the contained node is a Resizable, then the node will be kept resized to match the height of the ScrollPane's viewport. If the contained node is not a Resizable, this value is ignored.

Change

```
<ScrollPane AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" 
            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" 
            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0">
```

to

```
<ScrollPane AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" 
            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" 
            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" 
            fitToHeight="true" 
            fitToWidth="true">
```

Comment: This have solved the resize problem but, now the panes are so thin. How can I make the whole `ScrollPane` to extend vertically? I tried to set `prefHeight`, or `maxHeight` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sunflame that's a different question, but you can try using `minHeight`.

Comment: Did you put them on each TiltledPane?