# Javafx : ScrollPane in SplitPane cannot scroll

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scrollpane, splitpane

I have many panes in my `.fxml` file ( here is the earlier version of my fxml: [Javafx : SplitPane resize children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329829/javafx-splitpane-resize-children)) Now I want to fix the first two elements in the split pane in the top of my view, so I put them out of the `ScrollPane` but now the problem is that I cannot scroll the rest of the panes, and I have no idea why. I tried to wrap them into a `BorderPane`, another try was that to wrap them in a `SplitPane` so the those two panes become items in the `SplitPane` and the third item is the `ScrollPane` but none of the worked. Do you have any idea what did I miss, or any solution for this problem?

Edit : So here is the code that I have tried, so I put the first two elements out of `ScrollPane`

```
<TitledPane>
        <TextArea fx:id="taTop" wrapText="true" editable="false" prefHeight="100"/>
</TitledPane>
<TitledPane>
        <TableView fx:id="tableFrist" minHeight="120" maxHeight="120">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="column" prefWidth="200"/>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
</TitledPane>
<ScrollPane AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
        AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0">
    <SplitPane orientation="VERTICAL" fx:id="splitPane">
        <TitledPane>
            <TreeTableView fx:id="tableSecond">
                <columns>
                    <TreeTableColumn fx:id="columnTreeS" prefWidth="200"/>
                </columns>
            </TreeTableView>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane>
            <TreeTableView fx:id="tableThird">
                <columns>
                    <TreeTableColumn fx:id="columnTreeT" prefWidth="200"/>
                </columns>
            </TreeTableView>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane>
            <TextArea fx:id="taBot" wrapText="true" editable="false"/>
        </TitledPane>
    </SplitPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

Expanded state:
[image: Expanded state]

Collapsed state:
[image: Collapsed state]

So when I expand all panes there is no scrollbar so I cannot scroll down to the other panes.

Comment: Please show your code. We can't know what the problem is without seeing your work

Comment: There is the code in the link.

Comment: Firstly, about your other question, when you find a useful answer, upvote it. It rewards the answerer's efforts

Comment: Secondly, Show what you have tried to solve your **current** problem

Comment: Ok, can you please tell us in what way it isn't working? a screenshot of the window?

Comment: There are the images

Comment: Ok, and what is it supposed to be?

Comment: To be scrollable the part that is included in a `ScrollPane` but is not scrollable, as you can see at the first image there is no scrollbar, but there are panes those aren't visible, so I want to scroll down to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, in my controller class i have inserted this line:
`scrollPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(contentPane.heightProperty());`
and it solved my problem, I guess the `ScrollPane` had `Infinite` height so the scrollbar had never sown.